# oracle how to transpose columns into rows without UNION

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Assume, i have 4 columns in a table

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3
```

now i want to transpose that into one column but in 4 rows:

```
result
-------
someid
col1data
col2data
col3data
```

How can i achieve that?
Thanks!

Comment: you should use `unpivot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using `unpivot`.

```
select result 
from tablename
unpivot (result for colnames in (id,col1,col2,col3))
```

Comment: Is there a way to unpivot without having to manually list every column? I have a table of over 50+ columns, and that number expands each year with new column headers.