# how to convert column value to multiple insert rown oracle cursor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to copy value from our old db to new db where there is a change in the table structure.
Below is the structure of the table

Table1

`Table1ID, WheelCount, BlindCount, OtherCount`

For eg values of table 1 is like below

`Table1ID, 1,2,5`

Table1 is now changed to TableNew with the below

`TableNewID, DisableID , Quantity`.
So the value should be

```
TableNewID1, 1,1   here 1= WheelCount from table1
TableNewID2, 2,2   here 2= BlindCount
TableNewID3, 3,5   here 5= OtherCount
```

how to write a cursor to transform table1 value to the new table tableNew structure.

```
Table1

Table1ID   WheelCount  BlindCount  OtherCount
1             1            2          5
2             8            10         15
```

A master table defined to map disableid

```
DisableID Type
1          wheelCount
2          blindcount
3          otherCount
```

Expected structure

```
    ID     **Table1ID**  **DISABLEID**   QUANTITY
```

---

```
     1      1                1          1
     2      1                2          2
     3      1                3          5
     4      2                1          8
     5      2                2          10
     6      2                3          15
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [oracle how to transpose columns into rows without UNION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450776/oracle-how-to-transpose-columns-into-rows-without-union)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is a UNION ALL for each column you want to turn into a row.

```
insert into tablenew
select table1id,1,wheelcount from table1
union all
select table1id,2,blindcount from table1
union all
select table1id,3,othercount from table1
```

There are other, sleeker methods for avoiding multiple passes on the first table, in case it's huge.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood it.

Current table contents:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM table1;

  TABLE1ID WHEELCOUNT BLINDCOUNT OTHERCOUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          2          5
         2          8         10         15
```

Prepare new table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE tablenew
  2  (
  3     id          NUMBER,
  4     table1id    NUMBER,
  5     disableid   NUMBER,
  6     quantity    NUMBER
  7  );

Table created.
```

Sequence (will be used to populate `tablenew.id` column):

```
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE seq_dis;

Sequence created.
```

Trigger (which actually populates `tablenew.id`):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_bi_tn
  2     BEFORE INSERT
  3     ON tablenew
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     :new.id := seq_dis.NEXTVAL;
  7  END;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Copy data:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO tablenew (table1id, disableid, quantity)
  2     SELECT table1id, 1 disableid, wheelcount AS quantity FROM table1
  3     UNION ALL
  4     SELECT table1id, 2 disableid, blindcount AS quantity FROM table1
  5     UNION ALL
  6     SELECT table1id, 3 disableid, othercount AS quantity FROM table1;

6 rows created.
```

Result:

```
SQL>   SELECT *
  2      FROM tablenew
  3  ORDER BY table1id, disableid;

        ID   TABLE1ID  DISABLEID   QUANTITY
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1          1
         3          1          2          2
         5          1          3          5
         2          2          1          8
         4          2          2         10
         6          2          3         15

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: the i should keep the existing id as well.
second column is the id for the disable category . 
FID  DISABLEID   QUANTITY
1       1        1
1       2        2
1       3        5
2       1        8
2       2       10
2       3       15

Comment: That's unreadable, Jubi. Please, edit the original question, provide sample data and desired result.

Comment: yeah , i was trying to format in comment. i want to actually maintain the id also. i will edit the qstn

Comment: Comments, unfortunately, don't keep formatting. OK, I saw you posted what you want to have in TABLENEW. Could you do the same for TABLE1 (display its structure and contents as a table)?

Comment: i have updated tble structure

Comment: Thank you; I edited answer based on sample data you posted. Have a look, please.